# Hadoop logging and reporting

Tags: hadoop, client-server, thrift, scribe

Can we use Hadoop just for logging or just for reporting?
So i can experiment on diffrent things like logging with scribe and reporting with Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

you already answered the question, there are projects like flume, scribe which can help you collect the logs and you can do aggregation on that. You can also refer to following for other projects

http://blog.treasure-data.com/post/13766262632/real-time-log-collection-with-fluentd-and-mongodb
http://incubator.apache.org/projects/flume.html

Comment: I meant that can i use Hadoop only for logging or only for reporting.i know we can do reporting through pig etc . but i want to know how efficient it is for single purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop has both economic storage and powerful data analysis.  HDFS is a great place to put logs and the like because its price-per-terabyte compared to other solutions is very low.  Plus, when your data is in HDFS it's very accessible with MapReduce.  The whole pitch with Hadoop, too, is that you shouldn't be throwing away data.  You should collect all of it, and through MapReduce, start analyzing it and gaining insights that you would otherwise not have.